# Network issue with foscam & swanndvr

Tags: networking, router

Hi I have a wireless foscam & hard wired swanndvr. I have the foscam on my iPhone but I'm struggling to get the dvr to do the same. The local ips are different but the remote access ip is the same. How do I get them both on the same remote ip? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding (a router function) will allow you to accomplish connecting to different internal IP's from external devices.